# Regex (PCRE): Match all digits conditional upon presence of a string

Tags: regex, pcre

Using PCRE, I want to capture only and all digits in a single line, but only if a certain string (say "STRING99") is present anywhere within that line.

For example, consider these two cases:

```
a1 STRING99 2b c3d

a1 2b c3d
```

In the first case, I want the result to be "19923".
In the second case, I want an empty result.

I am not sure this is possible. It might work with a variable-length lookbehind, but this is not supported in PCRE. Furthermore, something like `(?=.*STRING99.*$)(\D|(\d))*` WOULD work, but "a repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration", meaning the second capturing group only captures the last digit. I am unable to find a workaround for this.

(This is obviously not hard to achieve with 2 consecutive Regex operations, but I want it in one formula.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex in `preg_replace`:

```php
^(?!.*STRING99).*(*SKIP)|\D+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNx0sm/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*STRING99)`: Lokahead to check if we have `STRING99` anywhere in input
- `.*(*SKIP)`: Match rest of the input till end and skip it
- `|`: OR
- `\D+`: Match 1+ non-digit

**PHP Code:**

```
$repl = preg_replace('~^(?!.*STRING99).*(*SKIP)|\D+~', '', $str);
```

Comment: This is elegant solution. Moreover ``(*SKIP)`` would be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a regex replacement with a callback function:

```php
$output = preg_replace_callback('/^.*\bSTRING99\b.*$/', function ($match) {
    return preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $match[0]);
}, 'a1 STRING99 2b c3d');

echo $output;   // prints 1992
```

The approach here is to first to match only inputs containing `STRING 99`.  Then on such matched we strip off all non digit characters.  Non matches would not have this replacement done.

Comment: I couldn't try this method because I'm not actually working in PHP but only using PCRE in Autohotkey. Thank you, however, for providing this alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*STRING99)|^.*(*ACCEPT))\d*\K\D+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ikJGXM/1) (where I replaced `\D` with `[^\d\n]` for demo purposes only since the test is performed against a multiline string).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*STRING99)|^.*(*ACCEPT))` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the string start position if after any 0+ chars there is a `STRING99` string (see `^(?=.*STRING99)`) or (else) the whole string is matched with `^.*` and the successful match is returned (the pattern is not parsed further)
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits are consumed
- `\K` - and discarded from the match memory buffer
- `\D+` - 1 or more non-digit chars (that will be removed eventually).

Comment: Thank you! This solution seems to work fine as well.