# Regex (PCRE): Match all digits in a line following a line which includes a certain string

Tags: regex, pcre

Using PCRE, I want to capture only and all digits in a line which follows a line in which a certain string appears. Say the string is "STRING99". Example:

car string99 house 45b
22 dog 1 cat
women 6 man

In this case, the desired result is:

221

As asked a similar question some time ago, however, back then trying to capture the numbers in the SAME line where the string appears ( [Regex (PCRE): Match all digits conditional upon presence of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672379/regex-pcre-match-all-digits-conditional-upon-presence-of-a-string/64672715) ). While the question is similar, I don't think the answer, if there is one at all, will be similar. The approach using the newline anchor ^ does not work in this case.

I am looking for a single regular expression without any other programming code. It would be easy to accomplish with two consecutive regex operations, but this not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try:

```
(?:\bstring99\b.*?\n|\G(?!^))[^\d\n]*\K\d
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BxQ2oD/1)

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\bstring99\b` - Literally match "string99" between word-boundaries.
  - `.*?\n` - Lazy match up to (including) nearest newline character.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `\G(?!^)` - Asserts position at the end of the previous match but prevent it to be the start of the string for the first match using a negative lookahead.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `[^\d\n]*` - Match 0+ non-digit/newline characters.
- `\K` - Resets the starting point of the reported match.
- `\d` - Match a digit.

Comment: You could also use the greedy `.*` to match the rest of the line, and match 1+ digits at the end :-) https://regex101.com/r/x3l70E/1 +1